# Elasticsearch delete documents from index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have an Elasticsearch cluster on Kubernetes, I also have a curator that deletes indices older than 7 days.

I want to change the curator to work according to a certain condition:

If document `key1=value1` delete these documents delete after 10 days, otherwise delete after 7 days.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Curator is limited to [index deletion as a whole](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html) and not at the document level.

What Curator does under the hood is call `DELETE index-name` and there is not way to configure it to call the [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) which is what you're asking for.